# GetActiveWindow returns 0

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

```
        IntPtr win = GetActiveWindow();
        RECT dimensions;
        GetWindowRect(win, out dimensions);
```

The above code seems to be returning a rect with 0 in it's dimensions.Right and dimensions.Left values. My references to the winapi are as follows.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

    enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint
    {
        GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
        GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
        GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
        GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
        GW_OWNER = 4,
        GW_CHILD = 5,
        GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true))]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner  
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner  
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner  
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner  
    }
```

GetActiveWindow seems to not be returning the window the user currently has selected. I noticed that if I change the above to the following it seems to work.

```
        IntPtr win = GetForegroundWindow();
        RECT dimensions;
        GetWindowRect(win, out dimensions);
```

EDIT: Code with checks.

```
IntPtr win = GetActiveWindow();
if (win == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //this triggers
    Debug.WriteLine("Win: " + win.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get window handle.");
}
else
{
    RECT dimensions;
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(win, out pid);
    Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(pid.ToString());
    if (GetWindowRect(win, out dimensions))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(dimensions.Top.ToString() + ", " + dimensions.Right.ToString() + ", "
            + dimensions.Bottom.ToString() + ", " + dimensions.Left.ToString() + "\nPID: " + pid.ToString());
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        int width = dimensions.Right - dimensions.Left;
        int height = dimensions.Bottom - dimensions.Top;
        Clipboard.SetImage(sc.CaptureArea(dimensions.Left, dimensions.Top, width, height));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString() + "\nPID:" + pid.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get window dimensions.\nPID:" + pid.ToString());
    }
}
```

SSCCE:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GetWindow
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr win = GetActiveWindow();
            Console.WriteLine("Win: " + win.ToString()); //outputs 0 to console
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: iam not familar with C# but are you sure that `IntPtr` is the correct substitution for an `HWND`? Especially in the context of 32bit vs 64 bit.

Comment: **Never** ignore the return value of winapi functions.  You don't have the friendly .NET exceptions to keep you out of trouble, error checking is *not* optional when you pinvoke.  In all likelihood, the function just failed because you passed IntPtr.Zero as the window handle.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that Marshal.GetLastWin32Error is 0 and the returned window is actually valid because I was able to get the process id with it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the two `GetWindow` calls.

Comment: They honestly make no difference to the issue, the first time GetWindow is called it always seems to return the same window that I got with GetActiveWindow. [This image](http://i.imgur.com/nPb7OD7.png) shows the output, the process in question is my Visual Studio window and the pid is correct. However the dimensions are wrong, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error is 0 and GetWindowRect returned true.

Comment: It's pretty much pointless for anyone to attempt to answer this until you start checking return values.

Comment: Upon further inspection it seems the calls to `win = GetWindow(win, (uint)GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT)` were circumventing the win32 error somehow. If I remove them I get an error of 1400 thrown every time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the only return value that wasn't checked in the above code was if GetWindowRect returned true or not, which I have checked in my code. Unless you were referring to the windows returned in which case I have checked those as well by being able to get their process id successfully using GetWindowThreadProcessId.

Comment: I can count 6 API calls where you fail to check the return value. Every single call you make fails to check the return value. I don't know why you are ignoring our advice to check return values. The documentation tells you to do it. We repeat the advice day in day out here. Please check return values. I propose that you do so and then edit the question to show the corrected code, and to report the outcome of the checks.

Comment: There I have shown the code with checks for the values and as stated in my previous comment the window handle being returned by GetActiveWindow is invalid. (this causes error 1400 if I allow GetWindowRect to use it). However GetForegroundWindow seems to work find if I use that instead, but it also not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How can we reproduce this? Can you convert the output into `Debug.Print` rather than `MessageBox.Show` and show the output. Please also print the value of `win`.

Comment: https://github.com/Renari/PushMinus/tree/active-window-issue when you run the program you can either use the context menu in your task tray to try to capture a screenshot of the active window or press Win+A and the issue will occur.

Comment: I should also mention the class that you're looking at above is "HotkeyHandler.cs".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not about to download that large project and build it. It would be nice to see the debug output that you collect. If you want us to run your program, please provide an SSCCE in the question.

Comment: The debug output is as follows: `Win: 0
Unable to get window handle.` Thus GetActiveWindow is not returning a valid window when I press Win+A.

Comment: I have also attached an example showing the issue in a small console program.

Comment: @Renari, you have answered your own question.

Comment: @Ben I have answered the original question however have not come to a solution to the issue. That being GetActiveWindow does not return the active window. GetForegroundWindow does indeed work however will lead to inaccurate results for what I'm trying to accomplish due to the fact that if an application is set to always be on top I do believe it is considered the foreground window and not the window that the user has selected. The above SSCCE should return the command prompt window however it does not.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the current issue.

Comment: The issue appears to be that GetActiveWindow is looking for a window "attached to the calling thread's message queue." When I am trying to get another applications window. In this situation I can just assume that my application is currently active since it shouldn't be possible to trigger the click event on the context menu without having the context menu open and thus giving it focus.

Comment: It also appears GetForegroundWindow doesn't suffer from the issue I thought it was going to cause (always on top windows aren't returned as the foreground window).

Comment: I wish you could have got the facts straight. In an earlier version you claimed a non-zero window handle. And your app was a GUI app. You absolutely have not got to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normal. `GetActiveWindow` gets the active window for the calling thread. If the calling thread does not own the foreground window, then `GetActiveWindow` returns `NULL`.

Comment: You can use GetForegroundWindow instead of GetActiveWindow